# How do verify Pinterest in Magento? Where is the index.html?

Tags: magento-community

I need to add a meta tag to  of index.html file or equivalent in order to verify my website for Pinterest. Where in Magento do I find this?

Answer (score 2):

Pinterest most likely just needs to verfiy on the homepage of your site. If you put the meta tag in the head.phtml file it should verify. That file should be located at:

app/design/frontend/[your_package]/[your_theme]/template/page/html/head.phtml

This will however put that meta tag on all pages of your site.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to add this to the home page

Go to `Admin -> CMS -> Page -> (select home page) -> Design` the add code below to "Layout Update XML"

```
<reference name="head">
    <block type="core/text" name="pinterest">
        <action method="setText">
            <text>
                <![CDATA[<meta name="pinterest-rich-pin" content="false" />]]>
            </text>
        </action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

To add it to all pages then add the code above to your local.xml

Comment: +1 Layouts are the best way of handling page specific things like this. Not only is it page specific, you don't have to run down a template edit every time something needs change. And it's readily available in the admin backend. If you want it on every page, create local.xml for your theme and add the above in the `<default>` section.

Answer (score 0):

For magento 1.9.2, what I did was:

- Copy the code from Pinterest business account  (meta tag)
- Go to backend admin panel: configuration > design > html head > miscellaneous scripts, paste the code

[image]

Here is what the meta code looks like:
[image]